# How to store servers load value in variable

Tags: linux, shell

I'm going to store last five minutes server load into a variable in a shell script. I use the following command which works perfectly:

```
    uptime | awk -F 'load average:' '{print $2}' | awk -F', ' '{print $2}'
```

> OUTPUT : 0.24

But when I create a shell script file it print whole uptime output.

Here is my shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
uptime = $(uptime | awk -F "load average: " '{print $2}' | awk -F"," '{print $2}')
echo $uptime
```

> OUTPUT : 19:39:22 up 52 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.03, 0.12, 0.20

What is wrong in my shell script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra spaces around the `=`, like so:

```
#!/bin/sh
uptime=$(uptime | awk -F "load average: " '{print $2}' | awk -F"," '{print $2}')
echo $uptime
```

This worked fine for me.